# Can it be possible to add delay in Console.WriteLine or in Console.ReadKey for having text displayed?

Tags: c#

It's in the Title, can it be possible to add delay in a Console.WriteLine ?

```
            //userAge
        Console.WriteLine("For security reason, you need to be 14 years old or higher to use this program, please enter your age");
            int userAge = Convert.ToInt32 ( Console.ReadLine() );
    if (userAge > 14)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're " + userAge + " you are old enough to use this program");
        }
    else {
            Console.WriteLine("You're " + userAge + " years old you need to use this program with the help of your parents");
            return;
        }
```

For context, I want that
if userAge < 14, then console write "You're ... years old, you need the help of your parents", but I want to add a duration for the text after it had been written, to be displayed with a certain duration and then the program closed. Does it is possible ?

Comment: What do you mean? A delay before it writes the line? After? During? After every character?

Comment: Hello, A delay after it write the line, like "here's some text" wait 4 seconds, quit the console. Thanks you, I should have been more precise

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thread.Sleep()` to delay the program for a specific amount of time.

For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("This will be closed in 2 seconds");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```